# iPhone application Verify Recipt on server during apple testing

Tags: iphone, storekit

quick question because I can't seem to find info on this but I have an application which is a paid recurring subscription app that is submitted to apple. As it stands now we verify store receipts using Apple's sandbox url on the server. While apple is testing the app (before it is approved) should we change that url to production or wait until after approval? Does it matter? Thanks!